# Как Вывести на экран фрагмент англ. алфавита, если заданы начальная и конечная буквы фрагмента?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Мне нужно взять и вывести в консоль строчные буквы английского алфавита. Например, в консоль вводят `b` и `h`. На экран выводит `b, c, d, ..., g, h`.

Comment: `while (a <= b)  cout << a++ << ' '; `

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто. Символ – это число. Мы можем проиндексировать любой символ вот так: `char sym = 'a' + index`. Да, так просто. А так же для него работает инкремент, а значит:

```c
int main() {
    char start, end;

    scanf("%c %c", &start, &end);

    <валидация, чтоб `start` и `end` были символами английского алфавита>

    for (register char i = start; i <= end; ++i)
        printf("%c ", i);
}
```

Вместо `printf` можно использовать другие, более эффективные функции вывода.

Comment: Будет стабильно работать только для цифр, об этом уже написано под другим ответом

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const std::size_t first = 3;
    const std::size_t last = 12;

    const std::array alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f',
                                 'g','h','i','j','k','l',
                                 'm','n','o','p','q','r',
                                 's','t','u','v','w','x',
                                 'y','z'};

    for (std::size_t i = first; i <= last; ++i) {
        std::cout << alphabet[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109363/discussion-on-answer-by-user393903-------).

Comment: @AK спасибо, что удалили их, но, к сожалению, он не может писать в чате (поэтому мне не высветилось "Хотите продолжить дискуссию в чате?")

Comment: @return может, я проверил: на [эту комнату](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/109363/discussion-on-answer-by-user393903-------?tab=access) стоит явное разрешение на запись для вас обоих. Если нет - пусть напишет, посмотрю ещё раз, что не так.